# Azure AD Connect Start-ADSyncSyncCycle causes error

Tags: powershell, azure, office365

We are using Office 365 Business and have our Active Directory synchronised using Azure AD Connect. According to the portal the synchronisation is working ok however when we try to run PowerShell commands on the server running Azure AD Connect we just get error messages.

For example trying to force a synchronisation using `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial` causes the below error. Similar errors happen when we run `Get-ADSyncAutoUpgrade` etc.

Does anyone know what the cause would be and how to resolve? It appears the synchronisation is actually working as the portal reports that it happened "X minutes ago" however we have Googled some parts of the large error below without much results.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN> Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle :
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: System.Exception:
Unexpected exception thrown. Action:
ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter::GetCompanyConfiguration, Exception:  --->
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Properties()
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String
propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Online.DirSync.Common.PrerequisiteChecks.TryMachineIsDomainCont
rollerCore()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.IsMachineDomainController()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.GenerateSyncToken()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.OpenProxyConnection()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.InvokeAwsAPI[T](Func`1
awsOperation, String opsLabel)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetCompanyConfiguration>
b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName, Action
action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName, Action
action)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.GetCompanyConfiguration(Boolean
includeLicenseInformation)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.AADConfig.get_CloudEnforc
edSyncSchedulerInterval()
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.get_C
urrentSchedulerSettings()
   at SchedulerUtils.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings(SchedulerUtils* ,
_ConfigAttrNode* pcanList, UInt32 ccanItems, Char** syncSettingsSerialized,
Char** errorString) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: System.Exception:
Unexpected exception thrown. Action:
ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter::GetCompanyConfiguration, Exception:  --->
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Properties()
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String
propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Online.DirSync.Common.PrerequisiteChecks.TryMachineIsDomainCont
rollerCore()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.IsMachineDomainController()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.GenerateSyncToken()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.OpenProxyConnection()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.InvokeAwsAPI[T](Func`1
awsOperation, String opsLabel)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetCompanyConfiguration>
b__0()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName, Action
action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName, Action
action)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServiceAda
pter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.GetCompanyConfiguration(Boolean
includeLicenseInformation)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.AADConfig.get_CloudEnforc
edSyncSchedulerInterval()
   at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.get_C
urrentSchedulerSettings()
   at SchedulerUtils.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings(SchedulerUtils* ,
_ConfigAttrNode* pcanList, UInt32 ccanItems, Char** syncSettingsSerialized,
Char** errorString)
   at Microsoft.DirectoryServices.MetadirectoryServices.UI.WebServices.MMSWebSe
rvice.GetSchedulerSettings(String& settingsDeserialized, String& errorString)
   at Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.Cmdlet.GetADSyncScheduler.Process
Record()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable
input)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork
(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndD
oWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](
PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings
settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSData
Collection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TOutput](IEnumerable
input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.LocalPowerShell.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.TypeDependencies
.InvokePowerShell(IPowerShell powerShell)
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.InvokePowerShell
Command(String commandName, InitialSessionState initialSessionState,
IDictionary`2 commandParameters, Boolean isScript)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.PowerShellConfigAdapter.S
chedulerPowerShellAdapter.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings()
   at
Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.Scheduler.StartSyncCycle(String
overridePolicy, Boolean interactiveMode)
   at SchedulerUtils.StartSyncCycle(SchedulerUtils* , Char* policyType, Int32
interactiveMode, Char** errorString)
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Ident...ADSyncSyncCycle:S
   tartADSyncSyncCycle) [Start-ADSyncSyncCycle], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationExc
   eption: System.Exception: Unexpected exception thrown. Action: Provisionin
  gWebServiceAdapter::GetCompanyConfiguration, Exception:  ---> System.Runti
 me.InteropServices.COMException
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(I
   nt32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Properties()
       at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String prope
   rtyName)
       at Microsoft.Online.DirSync.Common.PrerequisiteChecks.TryMachineIsDomai
   nControllerCore()
       at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.IsMachineDomainControll
   er()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.GenerateSyncToken()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.OpenProxyConnection()
       at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.InvokeAwsAPI[T](Func`1
   awsOperation, String opsLabel)
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetCompanyConf
  iguration>b__0()
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName
  , Action action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName
  , Action action)
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.GetCompanyConfiguration(Boolean in
  cludeLicenseInformation)
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.AADConfig.get_CloudE
   nforcedSyncSchedulerInterval()
       at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.
   get_CurrentSchedulerSettings()
       at SchedulerUtils.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings(SchedulerUtils* , _Config
   AttrNode* pcanList, UInt32 ccanItems, Char** syncSettingsSerialized, Char*
  * errorString) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: System.Exception: Un
 expected exception thrown. Action: ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter::GetCompa
nyConfiguration, Exception:  ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMExcept
ion
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(I
   nt32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Properties()
       at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String prope
   rtyName)
       at Microsoft.Online.DirSync.Common.PrerequisiteChecks.TryMachineIsDomai
   nControllerCore()
       at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.IsMachineDomainControll
   er()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.GenerateSyncToken()
   at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.OpenProxyConnection()
       at Microsoft.Online.Coexistence.ProvisionHelper.InvokeAwsAPI[T](Func`1
   awsOperation, String opsLabel)
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetCompanyConf
  iguration>b__0()
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName
  , Action action)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.ExecuteWithRetry(String actionName
  , Action action)
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.ProvisioningWebServi
   ceAdapter.ProvisioningWebServiceAdapter.GetCompanyConfiguration(Boolean in
  cludeLicenseInformation)
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.AADConfig.get_CloudE
   nforcedSyncSchedulerInterval()
       at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.SchedulerSettingUtilities.
   get_CurrentSchedulerSettings()
       at SchedulerUtils.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings(SchedulerUtils* , _Config
   AttrNode* pcanList, UInt32 ccanItems, Char** syncSettingsSerialized, Char*
  * errorString)
       at Microsoft.DirectoryServices.MetadirectoryServices.UI.WebServices.MMS
   WebService.GetSchedulerSettings(String& settingsDeserialized, String& erro
  rString)
       at Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.Cmdlet.GetADSyncScheduler.Pr
   ocessRecord()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerab
   le input)
       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndD
   oWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeede
   dAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOut
   put](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSett
  ings settings)
       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](P
   SDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings s
  ettings)
       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TOutput](IEnumera
   ble input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.LocalPowerShell.Invoke()
       at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.TypeDepende
   ncies.InvokePowerShell(IPowerShell powerShell)
       at Microsoft.Online.Deployment.PowerShell.PowerShellAdapter.InvokePower
   ShellCommand(String commandName, InitialSessionState initialSessionState,
  IDictionary`2 commandParameters, Boolean isScript)
       at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Synchronization.PowerShellConfigAdap
   ter.SchedulerPowerShellAdapter.GetCurrentSchedulerSettings()
       at Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Scheduler.Scheduler.StartSyncCycle(S
   tring overridePolicy, Boolean interactiveMode)
       at SchedulerUtils.StartSyncCycle(SchedulerUtils* , Char* policyType, In
   t32 interactiveMode, Char** errorString),Microsoft.IdentityManagement.Powe
  rShell.Cmdlet.StartADSyncSyncCycle

PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN>
```

Comment: Are you running PS as administrator?

Comment: Yes `PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN`.

Comment: Are you explicitly running console as admin though? If I just run PS console it does not, by default elevate me - even while logged in as a domain admin. Have a look at this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/wmExBWP.png

Comment: It's the same message even when I explicitly 'Run as Administrator'.

Comment: Jack, does this error occur after AAD connect installed? which version of you AAD connect? which version of your PowerShell?

Comment: Hi, Jack, does that issue resolved? please let me know if you need more help. if this issue resolved, could you please share it.